# Find number of solutions of an ODE with a property

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stucked on the following exercise:

> How many solution of $x'(t)=x(t) -e ^{-t^2}$ have the following property: $\lim_{t \rightarrow \pm \infty} x(t)=0$ ?

I tried to integrate in $[0,t]$, obtaining

$$x(t)= c e^t -  e^{t} \int_0^t e^{-s^2} e^{-s} ds$$

Now I'd like to take the limit, in order to note that $x(t)$ is unbounded, by I don't know how to handle that integral.

How can I move?

Comment: It looks that a necessary condition is $c=\int_0^\infty e^{-(s^2+s)}ds=e^{\frac14}\int_{\frac12}^\infty e^{-s^2}ds$, where the last integral can be expressed via the "error" function.

Comment: The argument is clear, thanks. But how did you go from  $$ \int_0^\infty e^{-(s^2+s)}ds$$ to $$e^{\frac14}\int_{\frac12}^\infty e^{-s^2}ds$$ I know the properties of $erf(x)$, but I can't understand how you got rid of $e^{-s}$ in the integral  @LutzLehmann

Comment: I just completed the square, $s^2+s=(s+\frac12)^2-\frac14$, the shift in the integration variable results in an opposite shift of the integration interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All solutions converge to $0$ for $t\to -\infty$.

The integral converges to a constant for $t\to+\infty$, while the exponential term diverges. To have any chance for the limit to be zero, it is necessary that
$$
c=\int_0^\infty e^{-(s^2+s)}ds=e^{\frac14}\int_{\frac12}^\infty e^{-s^2}ds
$$
Then the solution formula reads as
$$
x(t)=e^t\int_t^\infty e^{-s^2-s}ds.
$$
This is on one hand positive, on the other bounded by
$$
x(t)\le e^t\int_t^\infty e^{-st-s}ds=e^t\,\frac{e^{-t^2-t}}{t+1}=\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t+1},
$$
thus indeed converging to zero.